# android countdown timer cancel vs timeup

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I am just wondering when timeout occurs, `onFinish()` method is called and we can execute further code there. But for some reason if timer is cancelled either manually or because of error does `onFinish()` get called? Or it just cancels the timer without calling any method.

Here are My two Counters.

Counter1:

```
    class Counter1 extends CountDownTimer {

    public Counter1(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d(TAG, " Timer1 Finished");
                    //Add 2min to second timer


    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    /
    }
}

class Counter2 extends CountDownTimer {

    public Counter2(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d(TAG, "Timer2 Finished");          
    }
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

I have to add 2 min to second timer is its values is less than add 2minutes to its existing else it will continue with its timer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OnFinish() will not called at timer cancel you have to start it again, You can store time value in shared preference when application get crashed you have start time from saved time.

like

```
CountDownTimer countDownTimerFixed = new CountDownTimer(Time, Tick) {

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        RTSharedPrefUtils.saveStringPrefernce(RTSharedPrefUtils.KEY_DOWNLOAD_TIMER, millisUntilFinished+ "");

    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        RTSharedPrefUtils.saveStringPrefernce(RTSharedPrefUtils.KEY_DOWNLOAD_TIMER, 0 + "");
        this.start();

    }
};
```

if timer is canceled,

```
Timer=Long.parseLong(RTSharedPrefUtils.fetchStringPrefernce(RTSharedPrefUtils.KEY_DOWNLOAD_TIMER,RTSharedPrefUtils.DEFAULT_DOWNLOAD_TIMER));

            countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(Timer, Tick) {

                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {



                    RTSharedPrefUtils.saveStringPrefernce(
                            RTSharedPrefUtils.KEY_DOWNLOAD_TIMER,millisUntilFinished + "");
                    Log.d(TAG," Normalcount:\t"+ (Long.parseLong(RTSharedPrefUtils.fetchStringPrefernce(RTSharedPrefUtils.KEY_DOWNLOAD_TIMER,RTSharedPrefUtils.DEFAULT_DOWNLOAD_TIMER)))/ 1000);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                    RTSharedPrefUtils.saveStringPrefernce(
                            RTSharedPrefUtils.KEY_DOWNLOAD_TIMER, 0 + "");

                    countDownTimerFixed.start();

                }

};

countDownTimer.start();
```

Comment: This does answers my question. I am not working on downloading time etc. But still code looks good for Future reference. Before accepting this answer just want to know, Is this code working fine?

Comment: OnFinsh() will not call if we cancel timer. Code will works fine

Comment: I have two timers running. If one timer is finished I want to add two minutes to second Timer which is currently running(Add to its current value).
Can I use same code for that too.

Comment: I have to cancel second timer and add value of both timer's shared preference .And start second timer again with that value. Correct me if I am wrong .