# Timer stops an soon as the application stops

Tags: android, timer, android-service

I have an android background service that uses the timer inside it to schedule some task. It works absolutely fine as long as the application is running. but when I close the application the service is still running but the timer stops and no longer performs it task.
Please suggest some solution.

Service :

```
public class UpdateExpectedService extends Service {

public static final long NOTIFY_INTERVAL = 10 * 1000; // 10 seconds
private Timer mTimer = null;
 // run on another Thread to avoid crash
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}   
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "The new Service was Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();          
}   
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "service starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    // cancel if already existed
    if(mTimer != null) {
        mTimer.cancel();
    } else {
        // recreate new
        mTimer = new Timer();
    }
    // schedule task
    mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimeDisplayTimerTask(), 0, NOTIFY_INTERVAL);

    // If we get killed, after returning from here, restart
    return START_STICKY;
}

class TimeDisplayTimerTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // run on another thread
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // display toast
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getDateTime(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.i("ABC", "ABC");

                DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(UpdateExpectedService.this);
                db.addExpectedService( new ExpectedList("TEMP", "TEMP", new Date()));
            }
        });
    }

    private String getDateTime() {
        // get date time in custom format
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("[yyyy/MM/dd - HH:mm:ss]");
        return sdf.format(new Date());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20782789/android-countdown-timer-cancel-vs-timeup/20782901#20782901